# How to create a partial view of an external page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a question about how to create a partial view of an external page, for example, Google's in C# .NET Core.

What I want is like the iframe that loads an external page but the iframe is not allowed to be used in the company.

I already tried with

```
await Html.RenderPartial("_AuthorPartial");
```

and it didn't work for me

Comment: You cannot steal other people's work and present it as your own that easily. You would have to make a request, download the HTML and CSS (and possibly JavaScript) required to render it, and include all of that in your partial page.

Comment: Why would you want to do exactly what an iframe does when your company explicitly forbids use of an iframe?

Comment: what I will get is an external page that belongs to the company.

Comment: Then you should literally contact the people who maintain that section of the web app and ask them how to go about integrating that page, or what's on that page, in a way that complies w company policy. Most likely they may even give you the components you want if that's what you are going for

Comment: Iframes were created with the purpose of _frame_ ing content that does not belong to your website. In that sense you're depending on the Terms of that website.
If that's not possible, either by your company's policies, or by the framed website terms, you'll be better off simply redirecting to that's website.

Comment: there is a project that has the menu and several projects will communicate with it as microfrontend and it will be the menu options

Comment: When you are saying `an external page` could please include the structure of it? And how you are calling it within your project? Does your `an external page` belongs to the same proejct?